# C# disable TaskManager for localmachine

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I would like to disable the TaskManager with my C# app using Registery Key, NOT with HKEY_CURRENT_USER but with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

This is one of the things I have tried:

```
string subKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System";
RegistryKey regkey3;
regkey3 = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(subKey);
regkey3.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", unchecked((int)0x00000001), RegistryValueKind.DWord);
regkey3.Close();
```

Any suggestions for passing it for all users on not only CURRENT?
All my research bings me to use the HKEY_CURRENT_USER, which is not an options because of UAC that won't allow it on normal user sessions, and disabling UAC is not an option.

Comment: What exactly is the use case for this, to me I can only think of something malicious to use this for.

Comment: Ahhh ok that makes way more sense as to what to use something like this for.

Comment: @Nomad101 it is so the admin can disable TaskManager for all users, for a custom security app that on enable, disables explorer.exe(ready for terminal use) and being disabled, makes the users unable to reactivate explorer.exe or anything else...

Comment: No yea I got that sorry about the original comment. Honestly didn't think it through all the way.

Comment: @Romoku you did not read my question... i said NOT for CURRENT_USER... the example you posted is for CurrentUser

Comment: System/Network administrators should do this via "Local Group Policy" or "Domain Group Policy". It isn't something a programmer should do in their code.